# What are the other ways of getting longitude and latitude of mobile phone other than using JSR-179?

Tags: java-me, latitude-longitude, jsr179

`JSR-179` is an optional package so it requires `permissions` and certificate `signing`. So are there other ways of getting `longitude` and `latitude` of mobile device through `J2ME` ?

Comment: are you using S40 Series device ? @pheromix

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your Device with external GPS device via bluetooth and fetch GPS details in as `NMEA` Strings format. You can use `StringTokenizer` class to fetch the lat-lon details from `NMEA` Strings.

you can [read](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_read_Location_from_Bluetooth_GPS) artical for information.

One more way to your requirement is to fetch `Cell-Id`, and based on the Google's Reverse API, you can get Latitude-Longitude from `Cell-Id`.

Comment: what if the customer cannot afford the external GPS ?

Comment: then how can customer afford to develop such thing ? there should be a prerequisite decides, that this kind of API will be required, so you must purchase atleast this level device, hence no use of developing such code. for e.g. you can not use GPRS in Nokia 1100

Comment: Internal GPS or External GPS one option he must choose, otherwise no meaning of development. Nothing comes in free, you have to purchase something atleast.

Comment: are you using S40 Series device ? @pheromix

Comment: Even Fetching cell-Id from some device require permissions and certificate signing. Even after that there is no guaranty of getting cell-Id.